# Why do I get an array of zero

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, arrays, memorystream

myByte - all bytes are zero

a = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=="

```
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, m_workspace.ListPlatforms.ToArray());

    myByte = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    memoryStream.Write(myByte, 0, myByte.Length);

    string a = System.Convert.ToBase64String(myByte);
```

what could be the reason

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're calling `Write` when I suspect you meant to call `Read`. In other words, you're writing *from* a newly created (and thus full-of-zeroes) array *to* the `MemoryStream` which has your serialized data in. Using `Read` instead of `Write` will read *into* the array *from* the stream.

It would be simpler to call `ToArray` though:

```
byte[] myByte = memoryStream.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're writing the byte array into the `MemoryStream`, not the other way round. Replacing `Write` with read would fix your immediate problem.

But `MemoryStream` has a `ToArray()` method which already does what you want. No need to do it in such a complicated way.

Answer (score 1):

Reasons:

1. you didn't flush `binaryFormatter` so the `memoryStream` didn't even got written
2. what are you trying to do anyway!?

If (1) is correct, put using around both `memoryStream` and `binaryFormatter`.

Comment: BinaryFormatter doesn't have a Flush method as far as I can tell.

Comment: I'm sure you are right, but I couldn't read mind as good as you so I can see that he meant Read instead of Write.  So I guessed that in order for memoryStream to be written, some extra steps are required.